# Apparmor patches for linux kernel 2.6.31

Tags: linux, kernel, apparmor

We are working on an embedded system using a MIPS(broadcom) core.
Now i want to patch vendor provided 2.6.31 kernel with apparmor patches.
However I cant find them.
According to http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page the patches could be found in the Linux git tree at git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jj/apparmor-dev.git. However, that tree cannot be found anymore.(maybe lost after the kernel.org breach ?)

Where can I find this patch now ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.6.31 is quite old at this point; if you can get your vendor to supply you with newer kernel sources, that'd be best.

If they cannot, you can take the patches from a distribution-provided kernel package from that era -- say, the [openSUSE 11.2 kernel source rpm](http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/11.2/repo/oss/suse/src/kernel-source-2.6.31.5-0.1.1.src.rpm).

---

The primary AppArmor development repository is hosted on LaunchPad:

https://code.launchpad.net/~apparmor-dev/apparmor/master

The git repository you found was a mirror John made from the LaunchPad repository mainly for his own use. Somewhere along the way it was removed and replaced with:

git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jj/linux-apparmor.git

The `aa-next` branch contains John's checkins intended for the next release.

There are apparmor tarballs located at the [launchpad download page](https://launchpad.net/apparmor/+download?memo=10&start=10); the 2.5 tarball has patches for 2.6.24,  2.6.25,  2.6.26,  2.6.27,  2.6.28. The 2.5.2 tarball has patches for 2.6.36,  2.6.36.2,  2.6.37.

Comment: thx ! The launchpad release do not contain 2.6.31 patches, but the opensuse 11.2 rpm does have the patch. i'd like a newer kernel version also, but the upstream vendor does not have his very large patch set for higher kernel versions, unfortunately.